# how to put a variable in string method?

Tags: python

```
import math

myPi = math.pi

print('Pi rounded to {0} decimal places is {1:.2f}.'.format(2, myPi))
```

I am trying to modify this code by switching the .2f part by using the input function.

If I say that `x=int(input("put in an integer"))` and I want to change the '2' in the '.2f' part to x.. how can I do it?

Sorry for my bad description. I didn't learn python in English so it is hard for me to describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code.

```
import math

myPi = math.pi

x=int(input("put in an integer"))

print('Pi rounded to {0} decimal places is {1:.{2}f}.'.format(x, myPi,x))
```

Comment: `'Pi rounded to {0} decimal places is {1:.{0}f}.'.format(x, myPi)` also works

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `round()` function.

```
import math

myPi = math.pi
x = int(input("put in an integer: "))
print(f"Pi rounded to {x} decimal place is {round(myPi,x)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use [f-string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) for this, which is generally considered the best type of string formatting:

```py
import math
myPi = math.pi
decimals = int(input("How many decimals?"))
print(f'Pi rounded to {decimals} decimal places is {myPi:.{decimals}f}.')
```

That way, you can place the variablenames directly into the string. Note the `f` before the string. As you can see, you can use `{myPi:.{decimals}f}` to specify both the value *and* the number of decimals with f-string formatting.